# Android: Unable to call back buttonOnCklick

Tags: android, buttonclick

Actually I don't understand why it doesn't see the buttonOnClick listener?

```
public class GeneralActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // with or without these lines below 
    private View.OnClickListener buttonOnClick = this.buttonOnClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GlobalData.getInstance().gContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_general);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.licence)).setText(MySettings.Values().LicenceNo);
        Button connect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        connect.setOnClickListener(buttonOnClick);
        Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendall);
        send.setOnClickListener(buttonOnClick);
    }

    boolean clicked = false;
    public static String LICENCE = "";

    public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
        MessageBox.Show("Connect me");
        Button b = (Button) v;
        if (b.getId() == R.id.connect) {
            MessageBox.Show("Connect me");
                return;
```

Also,
In GeneralActivitry designer everything is written out - onClick for both buttons and this method referred to the GeneralActivity.

Pls, see the movie and tell me what's wrong now?
[youtube.com/watch?v=heD9QGKtusY&feature=youtu.be](http://youtube.com/watch?v=heD9QGKtusY&feature=youtu.be)

FULL CODE OF GENERALACTIVITY LAYOUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/licence"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30pt"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="1SAT"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="SATEST LICENCE NUMBER" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30pt"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
        android:text="CONNECT" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30pt"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
        android:text="SEND2ALL" />
```

Well, I don't like this site exactly because of that kind of people who set -1 without any reason for that.. they just like shitters in that pages.
I explained my problem with MAXIMUM example and even VIDEO.. WHAT ELSE do you need to see to get the question clear? Idiots.

Ok, let they live, it is the shit policy of this site holders..

Now you read carefully what was my error:

When I implemented OnViewListener interface I forgot to mark the method onClick with @Override and another "BIG" mistake was that the handler name onClick I wrote from UPPER LETTER **O**nClick..

Actually that was my main mistake. Before publishing my Q here, I try to understand everything by myself, and I tried all of the suggestions that guys gave me.. but the

> letter O and o

- hmm you understood )))

I am 30 years in software developing, and these kind of mistakes are the hardest mistakes I have ever met. Same like brackets [ { jr (..

Thank you all for you help.. I'll set the Answer to the first one.. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use built it OnClick method to do this for you: here is an example of how to do it

just don't forget to implement `View.OnClickListener` in your Activity
`

```
public class GeneralActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
// with or without these lines below

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GlobalData.getInstance().gContext = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_general);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.licence)).setText(MySettings.Values().LicenceNo);
    Button connect = findViewById(R.id.connect);
    connect.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button send = findViewById(R.id.sendall);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.connect:
            //TODO
            break;
        case R.id.sendall:
            //DO something
            break;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: @Override - you think that is the problem? (onClick)

Comment: onClick instead of OnClick and of course @Override )))

Comment: thanks to your post I found out that my OnClick was from O not o. And also, funny thing, but Java compiler should say me something like "The Overriden method OnClick doesn't exist in the specified Interface.." Right?

Comment: it should say something about it, but if you were using Android studio to build your app which is something I would recommend then it will do this thing for you

Answer (score 1):

**Option - 1:** You have already set the `onClick` listener to `button` from xml, so no need to set it again from `java` code. Remove those line.

```
public class GeneralActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // with or without these lines below 
    //private View.OnClickListener buttonOnClick = this.buttonOnClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ....

        //Button connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        //connect.setOnClickListener(buttonOnClick);
        //Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendall);
        //send.setOnClickListener(buttonOnClick);
    }

    public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
        MessageBox.Show("Connect me");

        if (v.getId() == R.id.connect) {
            MessageBox.Show("Connect me");
            return;
        } else if(v.getId() == R.id.sendall) {

            //Add your logic here
        }
    }
}
```

**Option - 2:** If you want to set the listener from `java` code, then remove `onClick` attribute from `xml` and set it like below from code:

```
public class GeneralActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean clicked = false;
    public static String LICENCE = "";

    private View.OnClickListener buttonOnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.connect:
                    // Your connect logic here
                    break;
                case R.id.sendall:
                    // Your send all logic here
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GlobalData.getInstance().gContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_general);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.licence)).setText(MySettings.Values().LicenceNo);
        Button connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendall);


        connect.setOnClickListener(buttonOnClick);
        send.setOnClickListener(buttonOnClick);
    }
}
```

Comment: @VitaliPetrov, Check my updated answer. Hope this help you

Comment: https://youtu.be/evpdN5leZl0

Comment: What is this? it says **it's private**

Comment: ok, it's public now

Comment: I tried already nearly everything. And I would like to get clear the way #1. what I have done so wrong that it says "Unfortunately..@ and in Log "Can't execute find OnClick".. I am Windows programmer for decades )) I see that in xml layout it's set onButtonClick and the startUpCode is also GeneralActivity. Problem is that Java execution machine doesn't acknowledge the rest of the codeBehind to that controls from layout.

Comment: Can you add your full `activity_general` xml?

Comment: Yes, updated...

Comment: It correctly work in my side. Probably there are some other problem

Comment: I set all your replies as +1

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oneButton);
    one.setOnClickListener(this); // calling onClick() method
    Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twoButton);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);

}
 //outside of your oncreate()

         public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.oneButton:
            // do your code
            break;

        case R.id.twoButton:
            // do your code
            break;

       default:
            break;
    }

            }
```

TIP: Enter new View. And then press Ctrl+Spacebar you will get the function auto generated.

Comment: What if I need one callBack for two and more buttons?

Comment: https://youtu.be/evpdN5leZl0

Comment: check the updated ans pls